Advice on equivalent sql query to dynamodb data modelling example
I am interested in using dynamodb for modelling my data for performance. I want to create a database of meeting events. This is an example diagram of data I have modelled based upon what I think dynamodb can do.
Can someone correct me if this is the wrong idea and how best improve this model.
See attached diagram:


Here is my advice to your proposed data model:

You cannot do a between function on the partition key. If your use-case is to get all events in a given time period, I suggest using an index. I wrote a blog post on the very topic.
Again, this looks like a use-case for an index where group is your partition key.
This is not a good fit for DynamoDB. You cannot index on a map or list type attribute, nor can you do geo lookups.


So yes this makes sense. I need an entry point which is specific (ie an id) as the pk, which I could sort by sortkey.

If you read the blog you'll see that if you don't intend to scale beyond 1000 WCU then you can have a single value as partition key, such as 0 and now you can sort all your items by sort key, not just items within an item collection.
